# Running SQL query by using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

At first, I've imported 2 tables into Spark from CSV files, by using the next commands:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/Users/Me/Downloads/T.csv")

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/Users/Me/Downloads/I.csv")
```

And now I want to run the next SQL command in Spark to get results:

```
> sc
> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
> val dataFrame = spark.sql("SELECT T.Name, COUNT(T.Name) FROM T JOIN I ON T.Id=I.Id GROUP BY T.Name ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5")
```

But when I run it, I get errors:

```
WARN  Hive:168 - Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
```

and so on.
Can someone tell me what I do wrong and why I get these errors?
I've also installed Hive separately. I also read that I have to add Hive dependencies into Spark but after an hour of googling could not find anything about that.
Can someone please help me with that?
I cannot run that SQL query =/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `sqlContext.sql` method it tries to look up the tables in Hive Metastore. So problem could be that Hive Metastore is not correctly configured or if it is you are missing `spark-hive` dependency.

Once you add the dependency you'll start getting another error that couldn't locate table `T` and `I` as those tables do not exist in the metastore yet. You are just trying to load CSV files and are querying against them.

Try following code to remedy that

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/Users/Me/Downloads/T.csv")
val df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/Users/Me/Downloads/I.csv")
df1.regsiterTempTable("T")
df2.registerTempTable("I")
```

and then issue the query you are using. Also I'll suggest you to use `HiveContext` instead of `SQLContext` as `HiveContext` has wider support for sql dialect.

Comment: thank you! Could you please tell me, how can I add that `spark-hive` dependency?

Comment: It depends on if you are using Maven or SBT. Follow https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive to add the correct version according to you Scala and Spark version.

Comment: You shouldn't need the HiveContext or SQLContext, though. It's available from the `spark.sql` method https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#sql-java.lang.String-